# Google chart plotting unwanted values

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a Google chart in my web page plotting values that the user inputs (result1 and result2).
I can't delete the values `[0,0]`. If I do, the chart will not render, but if I leave them in, there is a plot point on the 0 point in the x and y axis.
I need the chart just to plot `[result1, result2]`

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  "use strict";
  var result1 = document.getElementById('finalScore').value;
  var result2 = document.getElementById('finalScoreD').value;

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Quality', 'Delivery'],
    [ 0, 0],
    [ 'result1',  'result2']
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: '',
    hAxis: {title: 'Quality', minValue: 0, maxValue: 1, gridlines: { count: 3, color: '#000000' }, titleTextStyle: {italic: false}},
    vAxis: {title: 'Delivery', minValue: 0, maxValue: 1, gridlines: { count: 3, color: '#000000'}, titleTextStyle: {italic: false}},
    width: 370,
    height: 300,
    colors: ['#6db33f'],
    pointSize: 30,
    pointShape: 'circle',
    fontName: 'proximaNovaLight',
    fontSize: '15',
    backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent' },
    legend: 'none',
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a couple problems...

first, the values `'result1'` and `'result2'` are being used, rather than the actual variable values

this
`['result1', 'result2']`

should be
`[result1, result2]`

next, the input field values need to be converted to numbers.
you can use `parseFloat`
`parseFloat(document.getElementById('finalScore').value)`

keep in mind if something other than a number is entered, you could get an error
use `isNaN` to verify the number

after these changes, `[0, 0]` is not needed

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    "use strict";

    document.getElementById('drawFinalScore').addEventListener('click', drawChart, false);
    drawChart();

    function drawChart() {
      var result1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('finalScore').value);
      if (isNaN(result1)) {
        result1 = 0;
      }
      var result2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('finalScoreD').value);
      if (isNaN(result2)) {
        result1 = 0;
      }

      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Quality', 'Delivery'],
        [result1, result2]
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: '',
        hAxis: {title: 'Quality', minValue: 0, maxValue: 1, gridlines: { count: 3, color: '#000000' }, titleTextStyle: {italic: false}},
        vAxis: {title: 'Delivery', minValue: 0, maxValue: 1, gridlines: { count: 3, color: '#000000'}, titleTextStyle: {italic: false}},
        width: 370,
        height: 300,
        colors: ['#6db33f'],
        pointSize: 30,
        pointShape: 'circle',
        fontName: 'proximaNovaLight',
        fontSize: '15',
        backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent' },
        legend: 'none',
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data);
    }
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<input id="finalScore" type="text" value="1" />
<input id="finalScoreD" type="text" value="1" />
<input id="drawFinalScore" type="button" value="Draw" />
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```